# How to download the video from this website?

Tags: linux, video, ubuntu, download, wget

I want to download this video: http://www.collapsus.com/

Can I do this with wget or any other shell command ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest having a look at the page source, finding the shockwave urls and fetching them via wget.

Looks like you will have to wget http://video.collapsus.com/swf/Shell_26.swf